# How to fill nan based on first value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

imagine you have the following df:

```
d = {'description#1': ['happy', 'coding', np.nan], 'description#2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'description#3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}
dffinalselection= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dffinalselection


description#1   description#2   description#3
0   happy            NaN          NaN
1   coding            NaN         NaN
2   NaN               NaN         NaN
```

I want to fill the df with the first description#1 column value if NaN:

```
filldesc = dffinalselection.filter(like='description')
filldesc = filldesc.fillna(dffinalselection['description#1'], axis=1)
filldesc
```

However, getting the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column
```

How to workaround?

desired output:

```
description#1   description#2   description#3
0   happy            happy        happy
1   coding            coding      coding
2   NaN               NaN         NaN
```

Please help!

Comment: Your `d` and `dffinalselection` output doesn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply()` on rows with `axis=1` then use [Series.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill nan values.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'description#1': ['happy', 'coding', np.nan], 'description#2': [np.nan, 'tokeep', np.nan], 'description#3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

dffinalselection = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_ = dffinalselection.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(row[0]), axis=1)
```

```
print(df_)

  description#1 description#2 description#3
0         happy         happy         happy
1        coding        tokeep        coding
2           NaN           NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a possiblility to keep inplace values?

Comment: @Max What does *keep inplace values* means?

Comment: For example when there is a value at description#2, that it does not overwrite that value!

Comment: @Max `ffill()` is to filled value based on previous value. Sorry for giving a missleading answer. I will edit soon.

Comment: @Max Answer updated. Really sorry for not understanding your question well at first time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) method with `axis=1`:

```
dffinalselection.ffill(axis=1)
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to keep inplace values?

Comment: It seems that at least in version 1.1.3 I'm using, it's not implemented. Just use `dffinalselection = dffinalselection.ffill(axis=1)` instead.